# Mime type for zip file in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types

I discovered a weird issue in zip file's mime type when I worked on [a Symfony application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852017/set-mimetypes-not-working-for-zip-file-in-symfony).

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp), the mime type for zip file is `application/zip`. This is what I believe, too.

But when I upload a zip file in my Symfony app with IE, the mime type of that zip file is `application/x-zip-compressed`. When I upload a zip file in Firefox, the mime type of that zip file is `application/octet-stream`.

None of them is `application/zip` as I would like to believe.

The weirdest behavior of all, is Google Chrome. When I upload a zip file in Google Chrome, I can't determine the correct mime type for it. Although I ***am*** pretty sure that it's ***not***

```
application/zip   
application/x-zip
application/octet-stream
application/x-zip-compressed
```

The mime type for zip file in Google Chrome is an empty string, as I found out by dumping out the `sfValidatorFile` object returned. Note the `sfValidatorFile.type` is "" for zip file.

But the `sfValidatorFile.type` object returned for a jpeg file is `jpeg`.

Seems to me like there is a bug in either Symfony or Google Chrome

Futher info: It seems that Gmail interprets zip file's mime type as application/zip in Google Chrome. This is the correct behavior. Seems to confirm that it's Symfony's bug.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint somewhere and read the mimetype from the request?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of now, MIME type of a zip file is **application/octet-stream** in Google Chrome. :)

Comment: can we modified the MIME type from octet-stream to zip..? is there any setting in chrome or code in the application that we can use..?

Comment: It seems that it depends on the OS, chrome on Mac returns application/zip, on win7 application/octet-stream and on win8 application/x-zip-compressed

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for this?

Answer (score 5):

This is Google Chrome's bug not Symfony. I have the same problem with Google Chrome's ZIP mime.

I have my own application written in php.

When you write `echo $_FILES['yournameattr']['type'];` it returns empty string when you upload a zip file but when you upload a gif or jpeg file it returns image/jpeg or image/gif.

I have Google Chrome version 3.0.195.6 (beta).

Though if you need fast solution, you can use preg_match to check the file's extension (zip or not).

```
if (preg_match('/(.*)\.zip/',$_FILES['yournameattr']['name'])) {echo 'This is zip.';}
```

Comment: You reported the problem to Google Chrome?

Comment: The name field in the file array is passed by the client and only valid to the extent that the client sent you a file with the correct extension. In other words, it's not trustworthy.

Answer (score 2):

file.type in javascript

| os | brower | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| windows 11 | chrome | application/x-zip-compressed |
| windows 11 | firefox | application/x-zip-compressed |
| windows 11 | edge | application/x-zip-compressed |
| mac | chrome | application/zip |
| mac | firefox | application/zip |
| mac | safari | application/zip |

Comment: Thank you so much, as of 2023 and Chrome 109, with Windows 11 this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like there is a bug in Symfony.

A ticket has been opened at [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/6461).