# Mime type of zip file in google chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome

I have an application developed in CodeIgniter, and I have a very weird issue.  A zip file is correctly uploaded while using Firefox or IE, but in Google Chrome, it gives me an error.

I have checked in CodeIgniter's mimes files and they have support for
`application/x-zip`, `application/zip`, and `application/x-zip-compressed` mime types.

Which mime types should I add in my code to make it work in all the browsers including Google Chrome?

Comment: Why not look to see what Chrome is uploading? (Which is application/zip here FWIW).

Comment: @Quentin, that wouldn't necessarily solve the cross-browser issue. Safari might have a different mime-type too.

Answer (score 2):

Use zip libararies

```
/* file Zip.php */
/* Location: ./system/libraries/Zip.php */
```

and also way

```
add mime.php

'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed','application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now MIME/type of a zip file is application/octet-stream in Google Chrome. :)

you should look at here for more details
[Mime type for zip file in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856013/mime-type-for-zip-file-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Seems following links can help -

1. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856013/mime-type-for-zip-file-in-google-chrome/14138225#14138225)
2. [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=133803)