# Empty Mime Type

Tags: javascript, mime-types, w3c, fileapi

I'm trying to load .zip file (with type validation) - and its mime type is empty string. it's strange because it is reproducible only in chrome and only on few computers (!!!)

(I suppose it is chrome bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=133803)

it is not too good solution - to inspect file name if file.type is empty - so maybe smbdy can provide a betters solution

I've managed to find [Mime type for zip file in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856013/mime-type-for-zip-file-in-google-chrome/14138225#14138225) but it does not fit - I do not use Symphony

Answer (score 1):

better way is to detect mime type at server side based on File metadata.