# How to unzip a Zip file with MIME type application/octet-stream using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that I use to extract csvs' data from email attachments. The csv is zipped so i was using the `Utilities.unzip()` function but it suddenly stopped working so i debugged it and called the `getContentType()` method on the attachment which returned `application/octet-stream`. 
I found here [Mime type for zip file in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856013/mime-type-for-zip-file-in-google-chrome) something related but I cannot figure out how to unzip now using apps script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the `.setContentType()` method worked for me. Below is the gist of the code.

The attachment was either csv or zipped csv. `attch` is the email attachment object.

```
var csv,zip,data,blobs;
csv = "csv";
zip = "zip";
var ext = attch.getName().split('.').pop();
if(ext == csv){
   attch.setContentType("text/csv");                
   data = Utilities.parseCsv(attch.getDataAsString());
}else if(ext == zip){
   attch.setContentType("application/zip");
   blobs = Utilities.unzip(attch);
   data = Utilities.parseCsv(blobs[0].getDataAsString());
}
```