# Need a simple javascript example to download a zip file

Tags: javascript, download

I'm trying to add code on my webserver to download a file from our remote website. (I just used a Microsoft download file as an example)

```
<p>
<script type = "text/javascript">

document.write('<iframe src="https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/9/8/E9849D6A-020E-47E4-9FD0-A023E99B54EB/requestRouter_amd64.msi" size="0" width="0" height="0" style="display: none"></iframe>');

document.write('<table><tr>');
document.write('<td><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20pt; color: #666666;">Thank you for downloading</span></td><br />');
document.write('</tr></table>');

</script>  
</p>
```

This iframe does not work. I also tried:

```
<p>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function download(file, text) { 
var element = document.createElement('a'); 
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64, ' + encodeURIComponent(text)); 
element.setAttribute('download', file); 
document.body.appendChild(element); 
element.click(); 
document.body.removeChild(element); 
} 

document.write('<table><tr>');
document.write('<td><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20pt; color: #666666;">Thank you for downloading</span></td><br />');
document.write('</tr></table>');

var text = "any text"; 
var filename = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/9/8/E9849D6A-020E-47E4-9FD0-A023E99B54EB/requestRouter_amd64.msi"; 
download(filename, text); 

</script>  
</p>
```

But this didn't work either. I already tried suggested article/code of [Client download of a server generated zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948809/client-download-of-a-server-generated-zip-file)Anyone have a sample I can use or what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client download of a server generated zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948809/client-download-of-a-server-generated-zip-file)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me. I did try it.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn’t work. Note that saying “it didn’t work” is illegal on basically any Q&A site

Comment: I mean the browser never asked to save the downloaded file.

Comment: Did you receive an error?

Answer (score 2):

*Will something like this work for you ?*

```
async function downloadFile(fileData, fileDataContentType) {
try {
    
    const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: fileDataContentType });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'randomFileName';
    link.click();
} catch (error) {}
```

}

Comment: What do I put in for fileData and fileDataContentType when the function is called?

Comment: File that is whatever you wish the user to download, and the fileContentType is the type of file user will download. For example, to download a png image , the fileData would be the png image data , and fileContentType would be I believe 'image/png'

Comment: If it's a zip, exe, or msi, what text goes into fileDataContentType?

Comment: For zip  you can get the answer from this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856013/mime-type-for-zip-file-in-google-chrome#:~:text=According%20to%20w3school%2C%20the%20mime,zip%20file%20is%20application%2Fzip%20.

Comment: That code downloads the file, but it downloads 4 copies simultaneously when the "link.click();" is run. However, the code is only run once by putting document.write() in between each line.

Comment: Can you add a console.log inside the download function and check how many times it is printed out?

Comment: I did the document.write() and it runs just once.

Comment: Can you share snippet on how you are using this function?

Comment: Sure! Here is the code: ```<p>
<script type = "text/javascript">

async function downloadFile(fileData, fileDataContentType) {
try {
     const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: fileDataContentType });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'randomFileName';
    link.click();
document.write('1f<br>');  
}
catch(error){}
} 

downloadFile("https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/9/8/E9849D6A-020E-47E4-9FD0-A023E99B54EB/requestRouter_amd64.msi", "application/zip");
</script>  
</p>
```

Comment: I ran this code here  https://jsfiddle.net/s9r0yL4u/  , and file was only downloaded one time.

Comment: I did a refresh on the browser and only one came up. Thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to show an error if the file didn't exist, how would I code that in the 'catch' with 'error'?

Comment: The problem is that it is NOT downloading the full file. Only like 59 bytes.

Comment: It is because, you are passing text value (which is the url ) to the function.
Before calling this function , you need to call the url , and download data , then pass the data value to this function.