# HTML input type=file should show only wav files

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the HTML's input element of “file” type to only accept pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548194/how-to-get-the-htmls-input-element-of-file-type-to-only-accept-pdf-files)

I have basic HTML input tag and `content-type="audio/wav"`

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

by using this we will get chose file or browse file. When you click on chose file button this open system window which shows the all file.

But my requirement is I want to show only ".wav" in this popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't, at least with standard html controls.

Here you will find a list of attributes you can specify for input tag and there is nothing suitable. http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp

Comment: W3Schools is rubbish ( http://w3fools.com/ ) but even they haven't failed to notice (right at the top of the list) the `accept` attribute (although it comes with caveats )

Comment: <input name="file" type="file" accept="audio/x-wav"/>
Is not working in firefox.

Comment: @David Dorward: I thank you for the info on w3school, I didn't know about it. By the way: Are the info I'm providing wrong? Are the info provided into the page I linked wrong (provided that the accept attribute won't work in mayors brother and therefore it is useless)? In other words: why the downvote?

Comment: accept="audio/*" working fine in chrome showing audio type file in popup, same thing is not working in firefoz this is showing all kind of files. I don't know why. any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an "open file dialog, this will explain it to you:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10051298/how-to-use-openfile-dialog-in-c-with-aspnet.aspx