# How can I upload an image-only file with Vue.Js?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, upload

so my question is something that should be simple but I couldn't find any decent material to help me with this question, I just want the user to be able to send only image files on Vue.Js, someone who can help me? I'm not much of a question here because I can always find something to help me, but it wasn't this time.
Sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian and I don't have much practice hehehe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit file upload to be only images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561847/html-how-to-limit-file-upload-to-be-only-images)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using pure `HTML` as follows:

```html
<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I gonna test this in my project.