# Limiting the filetypes dropdownlist options in the asp.net FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I know how to validate this client and server side by extension and MIME type.  That's fine, implemented, ready to go.

What I want to do is in the file upload dialog there is the little drop down list that by default shows "All Files."  I have seen similar controls in other sites and programs that effectively sort the directory for the user by the different options in the drop down ( just music files or just images, sometimes with the "All Files" option, sometimes not) and limit the user from seeing any file that isn't in the list.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a consistent way to accomplish this the way you are wanting to without adding dependencies.

You may be able to make use of the [accept attribute of the input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp), but browser support for this is lacking. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) for more information.

Comment: Well, not what I was hoping for but it is an answer.  Thanks.