# How can I filter a FileDialog depending on a dropdown selection?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I think this is a two-in-one question.. one, is: How do you filter valid file types in a `FileDialog` for a Html page?

Im using ASP.NET MVC and currently showing the textbux/browse button this way:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Order.LoanInfo.FilePath", null, new { style = "width: 800px;", type = "file" })%>
```

and the second is : How could you do to filter the file dialog depending on the selection of a `dropdownlist`? I assume it would involve some `jQuery` and changing the attributes of the input in the DOM, but I dont really know what would need to be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a question like this earlier today.

There is not a consistent way to accomplish this the way you are wanting to without adding dependencies.

You may be able to make use of the [accept attribute of the input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp), but browser support for this is lacking. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) for more information.

Comment: :( its sucks that there is not default way like in winforms...

ok, thanks! I'll do what the links you post suggest :)