# 'Accept' attribute of input element is not working

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-input

I came across a browse file dialog-control tag in html and the tag was

```
<input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" accept="application/pdf"/>
```

but the 'accept' attribute doesn't seems to have any effect. I am using Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

according to the w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp), the 'accept' attribute is not properly supported by any of the major browsers. The filter inside the file browser dialog will not work.

You could use a javascript validation on the form onsubmit event to verify if the file type is correct, returning false otherwise.

Comment: I don't see in the page how it is not supported by the major browsers.

Comment: @BehnazChangizi The question and answer are both 5+ years old, and the answer is no longer correct. Most major browsers, including IE 10+, now support `accept`, and it's part of the HTML5 specification.

Comment: Still not supported properly in Dec 2015. For example, I'm trying to accept font files. I provide the following list of comma separated MIME content types to the "accept" attribute: "application/font-tdpfr,application/font-woff,application/x-font-bdf,application/x-font-ghostscript,application/x-font-linux-psf,application/x-font-otf,application/x-font-pcf,application/x-font-snf,application/x-font-ttf,application/x-font-type1".  When the dialog box opens, the only items listed in the filetype dropdown are "All Files" and "WOFF File (.woff)". So it's completely broken.  TTF, etc. are missing.

Comment: Even just 2 years ago, the discussion was about a changing "standard" and how only one browser, Chrome, implemented support, and not even consistently. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176#c3

Answer (score 0):

It seems like browsers have trouble following the IANA specifications found here:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

In my case, the application/pkcs* media types don't work at all, while for some reason application/x-pkcs12 works in chrome and partially(.p12) in IE. Firefox seems completely oblivious.

I also found this more optimistic discussion over here. [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

So, the best description would be "probably unsupported for uncommon formats", and with the x-pkcs vs pkcs confusion more or less unusable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

## Delimiter

[image: HTML5 accept delimiter]

I can confirm in some *modern* browsers that if you want the file dialog types to appear you need to use a comma as a delimiter:

```
<input accept="image/apng, image/jpeg, image/png" name="example" type="file" />
```

Comment: Yes, accpet working when open the window and apper support types, but not validate the type file