# How to filter filetypes in plupload's HTML5 runtime?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, file-upload, plupload

I'm integrating plupload with my ASP.NET MVC3 application, with the following settings:

```
var uploaderSettings = {
    runtimes: "html5,silverlight,flash,html4",
    browse_button: "browse-button",
    container: "upload-ui",
    drop_element: "drag-drop-area",
    file_data_name: "file",
    multiple_queues: true,
    max_file_size: "10mb",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Upload")',
    flash_swf_url: '@Url.Content("~/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf")',
    silverlight_xap_url: '@Url.Content("~/js/plupload.silverlight.xap")',
    filters: [
        {title: "Excel Files", extensions: "xls,xslx,csv"}
    ],
    multipart: true,
    urlstream_upload: true,
    dragdrop: true,
    multipart_params: {
        token: "@AuthToken()"
    }
};
```

From which plupload is generating an `<input type="file">` with the following items in the `accept` attribute (comma separated):

- `application/vnd.ms-excel`
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
- `text/csv`

In Firefox 12.0, it ignores the filter and allows selection of any filetype.

In Chrome 21, it doesn't work with the file extensions mentioned, but if I change the filter to image files (jpg, png, gif) it filters the Choose File dialog correctly.

I found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54009) on the Chromium bug tracker, which seems to be related, but was marked as fixed back in October 2010.

If I switch the runtime priority to silverlight or flash above html5, it works correctly, but I'd rather not do this as I lose the drag and drop file upload functionality.

Is this simply the limitation of browser support for the accept attribute, am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in plupload?

**UPDATE:** it appears this is a [known issue](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/526), and boils down to browser support for mime-type filtering.

Comment: Accept isn't HTML5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp so would have thought it should have wider support!

Comment: True, it's been around since HTML2 - however, so have a lot of HTML5 features; HTML5 is more a standardisation of random browser-specific features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it's not a good way of validating file types.

[accept attribute in input file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505334/accept-attribute-in-input-file-is-not-working)

It's only for hinting the OS to filter the filetypes within the dialog.

When I did this with PL Upload, I did it based on the extension server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
filters: {
             max_file_size: '100mb',
             prevent_duplicates: true,
             **mime_types:** [title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"]
         }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.