# How to make HTML file upload control to select dialog only image file types like jpg,png etc

Tags: html, jquery-ui

i want to select only image files only

Answer (score 2):

This is done by the `accept` attribute, but it is not supported by all browsers.

```
<input type=file name=photo size=20 accept="image/*">
```

See also [File input ‘accept’ attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult using the standard HTML upload control.

If you can require your users to have Flash, [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) is a very fine alternative. It's even possible to filter the files the user sees in the "choose file" view by extension.

[Here's](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/featuresdemo/index.php) a demo (change the `file_types` field to test).