# restrict file upload selection to specific types

Tags: html, file-upload, fileapi

Anyway to restrict the selection of file types via the `<input type="file" />` element?

For instance, if I wanted only images types to be uploaded, I would restrict the possible selections to (image/jpg,image/gif,image/png), and the selection dialog would grey out files of other mime types.

p.s. I know that I can do this after the fact with the File API by scanning the .type attributes. I'm really trying to restrict this before hand.. I also know I can do this via flash, but I do NOT want to have use flash for this.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is an html attribute for this specific purpose called `accept` but it has little support across browsers. Because of this server side validation is recommended instead.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

If you don't have access to the backend have a look at a flash based solution like [SWFUpload](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/).

See more on this here: [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Comment: According to w3schools `the accept attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 6.` No version numbers of Firefox, Opera or Chrome were specified.

Answer (score 8):

It's better to let user select any file, and then check its type - this is better supported by the browsers:

```
var
    file = (el[0].files ? el[0].files[0] : el[0].value || undefined),
    supportedFormats = ['image/jpg','image/gif','image/png'];

if (file && file.type) {
    if (0 > supportedFormats.indexOf(file.type)) {
        alert('unsupported format');
    }
    else {
        upload();
    }
}
```

*You can also check for file size using file.size property.*

Comment: The question was about how to do it, not if you think this is the good way to proceed.