# Restrict file select input to single directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am going to use a bootstrap styled input as a file selector.

```
<div class="input-append">
   <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButtons" type="file">
   <button class="btn" type="button">Select File</button>
</div>
```

I have several on one page... one to select images, one to select an MP4 clip, and another to select a flash file.

The media files will go into separate directories on the harddrive or on the server. (Right now i am building this offline as a demo, so I need to select files from a local drive)

The directory structure looks like this:

```
demo.html
  |
  media------
            |
            ---image
            |
            ---flash
            |
            ---video
```

Right now it is confusing... the user can select an image with the video selector, a video with the image selector, etc... I figured this could be prevented if i can direct the user to the proper directory.

Lets just deal with the image file selector, and I'm sure i can modify the code for the other media selectors.

What do I need to do do to make sure the Image File Selector will only go to the "image" directory to select a file?

Comment: No, you do not want to restrict by "directory". How do you know where the user keeps *his files* on *his hard drive*? It makes no sense. What you want is to restrict *by filetype*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [restrict file upload selection to specific types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575482/restrict-file-upload-selection-to-specific-types)

Comment: The demo will be on my harddrive. I know where the files are. However, this will eventually be on a server as part of an application, where an LMS will put files into a specific directory. When this is part of larger application, we want the users to be able to access uploaded media files from a public directory, but we don't want them accessing any other directories on the server. I hope that makes sense. Additionally, the "accept" attribute is not currently supported in any browsers.

Comment: So there *will* eventually be a server and a client, and the client will select files on *his* hard drive to upload to the server? Either way though, because of the aforementioned conundrum, you cannot restrict a file input element to a specific directory. If you want the user to browse files on the server, just list out the existing files on the server and let the user pick one; no file input necessary at all.

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. I've not done this before, so i wasn't sure how to go about it. I was trying to simulate what wordpress does when you select an image that has already been uploaded. But now after I have read your post, I realize that it displays a list of files and allows the user to select one from the list, rather than directing someone to a directory. I was going about it incorrectly.