# Fileupload with jQuery: Ability tho show (select) only files with allowed extension(s)?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

Is there any functionality to determine that which files may be chosen, if I use a file-upload-input-element and I click on "browse" and only see e.g. PDF Files ? The allowed extensions can maybe readout from an array before?

p.s. the link above is not a cross browser solution..

Comment: have you tried anything till now ??

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575482/restrict-file-upload-selection-to-specific-types

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak: it is not cross-browser solution..

Comment: i dont think this is possible

Comment: it should be, on the todays web..

Comment: @user2819288 in that Q&A, it talks about _a flash based solution like_

Comment: thank you but, we may not use flash.. if you think, this question is important and you also need an answer, please vote up the initial question.

Comment: The second solution offered in the linked question, using the HTML5 File API to check before the file is actually uploaded, is as cross-browser as it gets. For older browsers, you will have to reject the data _after_ it is submitted. If you tell the user beforehand what file types are accepted and he uploads another one regardless in an old browser, then that’s mainly his problem.

Comment: RE: then that’s mainly his problem -> it is currently my problem :)

Comment: No, there is no way to do this cross browser.  A quick search on google or SO would have already told you this.

Comment: Currently there is no solution, I know that, but there should be a solution..

Comment: Maybe you can post a request on the forums of the developers of browsers ;-)

Comment: good idea dear putvande ;) 

p.s. @RayNicholus don't be a know-it-all ;)

Comment: p.s. @RayNicholus please don't vote down my questions. If you do not know an answer you better keep silent.. Everytime there is a wisenheimer, mischief-maker.. This is incredibly annoying, don't demotivate the people asking..

Comment: Don't want down votes?  Then don't post poor questions that show no research effort.

Comment: your brainpower is poor, that's the reason..

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a jquery plugin that approaches this problem. It uses HTML5 to detect the chosen file mimetype. All you have to do is to find out what mimetype is the kind of file that you want to allow.

[Accept Method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/)