# USER can only input pptx files

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Does anyone know if there is a way to make it so that the file drop box in apex only accepts powerpoint files? I can't find any information on this.This is the kind of drop box I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: That looks like a custom solution. Assuming you mean file input, does this answer your question? [restrict file upload selection to specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575482/restrict-file-upload-selection-to-specific-types)

Comment: @evolutionxbox - this is not a custom solution. In APEX 21.2 (not sure if available in earlier versions) if you make a Page Item of type File Browse... and under settings change Display As to Block Dropzone, it will appear just as it shows in the screenshot.

Comment: @EJEgyed it's custom since it does not exist as a part of standard HTML or WebAPIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the plug-in that you use. For example, in my application, I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone) and it has setting for accepted file types: [image]

If the plugin does not have a setting for the accepted file types, you may need to observe DOM structure of the element and reach to `<input>`tag of DOM by JQUERY and use accept attribute of HTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept)