# How to filter input type="file" dialog by specific file type?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict the browser to JPG files when I click on browse button of the `<input type="file">`.

Is it possible to browse for specific file types?

Comment: What kind of upload button? HTML file input? Flash? Something else?

Comment: where is your file ? in your local machine or on web ?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: its a Jsp page and I am using multipartrequest to upload the file

Answer (score 103, accepted):

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp:

> The accept attribute is supported in all major browsers, except
>   Internet Explorer and Safari. Definition and Usage
>
> The accept attribute specifies the types of files that the server
>   accepts (that can be submitted through a file upload).
>
> Note: The accept attribute can only be used with `<input type="file">`.
>
> Tip: Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads
>   should be validated on the server.
>
> Syntax `<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type" />`
>
> Tip: To specify more than one value, separate the values with a comma
>   (e.g. `<input accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*" />`.

Comment: Thanks.. But how to fix it for IE??

Comment: You don't fix it. That's something you have no control on. Just make it clear in the UI that what the user should select is an image, and validate it at server-side. That's what "File uploads should be validated on the server" means.

Comment: This makes mp4 unselectable in Safari. You also need to specify `video/mp4`.

Comment: FWIW IE 11 does respect this attribute

Comment: And MS Edge fails to respect it https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1937551

Comment: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is the reference on MDN

Answer (score 160):

This will give the correct (custom) filter when the file dialog is showing:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp, .tif, .tiff|image/*">
```

Comment: @jpoppe it's a small typo. You can actually edit the answer and fix it if you wish. :)

Comment: @jpoppe, thanks for pointing that out, it has now been corrected :)

Comment: Ha! Didn't know you could actually specify the extension. I only though it had to be the mime type. But be mindful of this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept , specifically annotation number 1

Answer (score 3):

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'file';
      input.accept = '.jpg,.jpeg,.png'
      input.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom attribute to `<input type="file" file-accept="jpg gif jpeg png bmp">` and read the filenames within javascript that matches the extension provided by the attribute `file-accept`. This will be kind of bogus, as a text file with any of the above extension will erroneously deteted as image.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadExcel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Upload Excel File" />
```

.

```
$('#btnUpload').click(function () {
    var uploadpath = $('#FileUploadExcel').val();
    var fileExtension = uploadpath.substring(uploadpath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, uploadpath.length);

    if ($('#FileUploadExcel').val().length == 0) {
        // write error message
        return false;
    }

    if (fileExtension == "xls" || fileExtension == "xlsx") {
        //write code for success
    }
    else {
        //error code - select only excel files
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: @slavoo ~ surely to use ASP inputs the OP would need to be running ASP? Why the addition in your edit? UserAK47's answer does not required them.

Comment: @pebbl Open revisions of this post and switch to `side-by-side markdown` on revision no.2, you can see asp inputs was here before my edit, but is not visible, because it is out from code formating. I fix format only.

Comment: @slavoo ~ ah that makes sense... otherwise I would have though you slightly odd :) ty for the clarification.

Comment: @pebbl This jquery code will with ASP Control will allow to filter only specific type of files to be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accept attribute along with the . It doesn't work in IE and Safari.

Depending on your project scale and extensibility, you could use Struts.
Struts offers two ways to limit the uploaded file type, declaratively and programmatically.

For more information: 
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-FileTypes

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general structure for using it:

```
<input type="file" accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
```

To specify more than one value, separate the values with a comma

For example

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
```

or

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*" />
```

More about attribute values

- file_extension: Specify the file extension(s) (e.g: .gif, .jpg, .png,
  .doc) the user can pick from
- audio/*: The user can pick all sound files
- video/*: The user can pick all video files
- image/*: The user can pick all image files
- media_type: A valid media type, with no parameters. Look at IANA
  Media Types for a complete list of standard media types

---

Enjoy...