# about filter filetype that are uploaded with Kendo ui in mvc razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, kendo-ui

i use Kendo upload for uploading image, but i can't filter file types that are uploaded.
i use this code to filter it to just ".jpg" file. i don't know how can i change and use it for all of image extensions like ".png", ".gif" ,...
and this code is case sensitive. it means that if file extension is same ".jpg", it doesn't recognize it.

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    $.each(e.files, function(index, value) {
      if(value.extension != ".JPG") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please upload jpg image files");
      }
    });
};

// initialize and configure an Upload widget with a select event handler
$("#photos").kendoUpload({
    select: onSelect
});
```

how can i change and correct it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported and it hardly depends what browser exactly you target. Basically you can apply the accept attribute once the Upload **is initialized** like this:

```
$('#uploadName').attr('accept',"audio/*,video/*,image/*")
```

More information about that attribute you can find in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type).

Comment: ,it doesn't filter file to image , it just shows image files when user selects them. He can change showing it to "all files" and select another filetype like *.txt and etc.