# Input file's accept attribute was not working for .pdf why?

Tags: html

I tried this Code:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf" />
<input type="file" name="upload" accept=".pdf" />
```

accept attribute doesnt seems to have any effect pls help me

Thanks Advance

Comment: What does it not work on? Any particular browser?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do for you that is not happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter input type="file" dialog by specific file type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type)

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri both questions are different. this question is specfically to pdf format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accept` attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 6.

Comment: Tested in IE 10 - not working there.