# Asp.net Custom File Upload (not CSS Related)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm being asked to implement (if possible) a way to restrict the local folders (or directories) when uploading a file.

This is the scenario:

> I'm doing a web app where the user is going to be able to upload BOM
>   files (xls, doc, pdf), Inventory files (xls only) and some other type.
>   The thing is that ALL of the BOM files, Inventory Files, Drawing
>   files, etc, are on specific locations. (Drive F:\BOM, G:\BOM\
>   Z:\Drawings, etc) so they want to only allow the user to browse the
>   specific drive or folder for the specific file type.

As far as I know, that's impossible. But if there's a way to do it, please help.

Comment: At most, it seems that you can only restrict file type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type.

Comment: maybe flash or html5 custom file browser dialog can archieve the target, however each pc isn't the same, how do you add the config to restrict for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found some jquery plugin to solve this issue, I can't allow the user to select multiple files at once, but instead choose them one by one and then with one click upload them all..

I know that with .net framework 4.5 it can be done without a problem, we are using .net framework 4.0 and VS 2010 and AFAIK we can't use 4.5 on it.

Thanks a lot for the help :)