# angular Directive - file reader not firing.. on file load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to read the data of the uploaded image file in angularjs. but as like expected, the file readers `onload` functionality not working.

any one help me here to fix this issue and read a image file to get it's data.

here is my code :

```
app.directive('uploadImageFile', function () {

  return {

    link : function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

      var inputFile = element.find('.upload-field');

       element.on('click', function () {

         inputFile[0].click();

       });

       inputFile.on('change', function () {


            var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function ( loadEvent ) {

                          console.log("load event", loadEvent.target.result); //nothing consoling here

           }

       })

    }

  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3H1BNJ3geSrWwkMdjAgM?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt add the `readAsDataURL` api which triggers the load event and `event` object that is received on change

**Corrected code:** [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rod3FC0Oodfo1k712am2?p=preview)

```
inputFile.on('change', function (e) {
       console.log("Changed");
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function ( loadEvent ) {
          console.log("load event",   loadEvent.target.result);
       }
       reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
})
```

Comment: How can I prevent a user uploading other than image file? do you have any idea? - thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type