# How to display image after selecting using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I have one image icon, when user will select that icon the file dialog will open and user will select the image.After selecting the image the image should display on that image icon.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="image-upload">
  <label for="bannerimage">
   <img src="{{attachImage}}"/>
  </label>
  <input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="bannerimage"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}"  custom-on-change="uploadFile" required="required" ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);"  ngf-multiple="true">
</div>
```

my controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.attachImage="upload/logo.png";
$scope.uploadFile = function(event){
  console.log('event',event.target.files);
  var files = event.target.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded; 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};

$scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    //var data={'image':e.target.result};
    // $scope.stepsModel.push(data);
    //$scope.myImage=e.target.result;
    $scope.attachImage='';
    $scope.attachImage=$scope.myImage;
  });
});
```

Here i need when user will select the image the image will display on that particular image icon.Please help me.

Comment: Where are setting the value of $scope.myImage?  try using ng-src instead of src.

Comment: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html implements this feature in angular.js. perhaps you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524466/angular-directive-file-reader-not-firing-on-file-load/34525202#34525202 this should help you. OP is also trying to achieve same as you. Have a look at the custom directive.

Comment: Thanks all..I have already done this.

Comment: Use `ngf-thumbnail` or 'ngf-src'. There are plenty of samples on the github page and demo page. `ngf-thumbnail` will resize the image to the smaller size in case the image you are selecting is too large and could cause the browser to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use  reader.onloadend  instead of  reader.onload

```
reader.onloadend = function () {
    // set $scope.attachImage to reader.result;
  }
```