# better apply file format filter for input type "file"

Tags: html

Even after applying filter like

```
<input type='file' accept='application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, 
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,text/plain, application/pdf, image/*' 
multiple='multiple' style='font-size:large;' />
```

when the file selector opens,in the filter dropdown at the bottom right corner there is still an option to select "All Files" and select a file of any format that is out of the filter applied.
[image]

How do we avoid "All files" option from the file selector and allow only file formats that are only in the filter??

The above mentioned filter is applied alright but the problem is since there is an option to go for "All Files" and select any file the user wishes to,the purpose of the applied filter is not fully served.
I just want to let the user stick to none other the file formats mentioned in the filter. I know i can do the server side validation ,which i'm already doing, but still i'm looking for solution which allows me to restrict at the client level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter input type="file" dialog by specific file type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type)

Comment: Since a file can be an image and still have a file extension of `.myimge`, the _All files_ is need, and can't be disabled either (even if you want to)

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for the response,if in WinForms when a filter is applied for an "OpenFileDialog" control the file selector doesn't show "All Files" option but the filter that are applied

Comment: In WinForms, yes, but in HTMLForms, no ... and when doing native programming, one almost always can do stuff like that

Comment: @LGSon why not??!! In both the case,html or winforms, the file selector is fired up by the WIndows(OS)

Comment: I can't actually say _why_ it won't work the same in HTMLForms, it just doesn't