# How to allow <input type="file"> to accept only Lottie files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lottie

I need to upload only Lottie file through `<input type="file">` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter input type="file" dialog by specific file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="File1" type="file"  accept=".lottie"  />
```

Comment: Actually you just want to upload the json file and render Lottie with the content in json? @Darshan