# Input type file accept not showing PPS files

Tags: html, mime-types

This is my upload input and no matter what I try it refuses the display Powerpoint PPS files.

It displays PDF, PPT, PPTX, PPSX but not PPS

```
    <input type="file"
    accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
 name="upldInput"/>
```

The behavior is same in all the browsers, no one shows PPS files.

Comment: Still looking for a solution

Comment: I updated my answer with more info. If lack of FF support is a deal-breaker, feel free to remove the "accept" check and see if someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a MIME type that works. However, the following *does* work:

`<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,.pps" name="upldInput"/>`

Apparently you can [mix and match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503561/453277) file extensions and MIME types. On Chrome 25 and IE 10 (PC) this gives the desired behavior, i.e. only the matched MIME type(s) *or* extensions are shown.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GGFVv/

I've also tried mixing multiple extensions and multiple MIME types, which also seems to work.

```
<input type="file" 
    accept=".pps,
    .jpg,
    .txt,
    application/pdf,
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow,
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" name="upldInput"/>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GGFVv/2/

I should note that file extension filtering does not seem to work in Firefox 19. I imagine this is because of the differences between the behavior defined by the W3C and the WHATWG.

- [W3C's definition of `accept`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.accept)
- [WHATWG's description of how user agents should handle `accept` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept)

The original mention of `accept` (in 1995!) is somewhat vague:

> Allow an ACCEPT attribute for INPUT tag, which is a list of media
>   types or type patterns allowed for the input.

Firefox appears to default to "all files" when it finds a value it doesn't recognize, so this is somewhat user-friendly (though not ideal).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** did you try to simply add: `accept=".pps"`?

```
<input type="file"
   accept="application/pdf,
      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
      application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow,
      application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,
      .pps"
   name="upldInput"/>
```