# .pps extension is not displayed in file upload dialog's file filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, plupload

On file upload my web application displays all other required file extension except **.pps** when browsed using Firefox(32.0) browser with my system's OS(Windows 7) having latest updates.

Even I tried with given demo in [Input type file accept not showing PPS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708332/input-type-file-accept-not-showing-pps-files) but didn't display .pps extension.

Am I missing any updates?

I expect you inputs on this regards, please.