# Don't allow certain File types while upload

Tags: jsp, file-type

I am implementing file upload functionality in this way

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
```

Now I want to restrict the user with some file types means when browse window will open he will be able to select all the files 
except `.bin` & `.dat`.

Means user will not be able to see that files with type .bin and `.bat` others he can see it and can go upload them.

I am familiar with `accept` attribute but, but it's not useful in my case because user should be able to select any file type except these two.

So how can achieve this without validation ?

```
I want to provide such a functionality that when user clicks on browse button and open a browse window to select a file , he should be able to see only files without .bin or .dat extension
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look gere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: Thanks for quick response, But using `accept` we have to specify file types which we want to allow to user select, and we can't mention all the file types in `accept`. we just don't want to see specified file types to user ,so there will be no chance to select them, & it will reduce our validation also.

Comment: Ok, maybe you need to do this validation via javascript in that case...

Comment: "*Now I want to restrict the user with some file types means when browse window will open he will be able to select all the files except `.bin` & `.dat`*". This not defined in the HTML specification. "*So how can achieve this without validation ?*". No you **never**. At anytime, the client side validation is always wonky (you should do it for the ease of use but you can never rely upon it). Do it right on the server side (must).

Comment: @Lion so you mean to say user will able to see `.bin & .dat `files but we have to provide client side validation if they select such type of file.right?

Comment: @what should I need to do on server side ?

Comment: A user can upload any type of files using the file browser. We can't prevent users from picking up only a specific category of files like `.bin` and/or `.dat` as you say. Validation is mandatory. You can do validation on both sides, on the server-side as well as on the client-side but one can never trust the client-side validation. It should however be done for easy interactions. The validation is relied upon only when you achieve it on the server side. If I were you, then most of the time, I would be using a file-upload-widget that could upload files with client-side validation.