# How to filter xls,xlsx and csv extension files in browse button of form tag of html?

Tags: html

how to filter excel,csv files while browsing.

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
`enter code here`Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 1):

Using the attribute "accept" with .xls, .xlsx, .csv. I guess.