# Symfony2 upload a few count of files

Tags: file, symfony, upload, doctrine-orm, multifile-uploader

I am new in symfony2 and i got one problem. I need to upload a few count of files assigned to one news. So, problem is i don't know how. 
I've read about [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html). But, 
1) I need to upload a few amount of files 
2) I need to use one to many relation(One news and few images)

I don't ask you to give the working code, but to give me link what to read to understand it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step

Answer (score 2):

How to handle file upload: 
[Symfony2 file upload step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step)

When you make that work, make it a collection of uploads.
A tutorial on how to embed a collection of forms is here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html