# Symfony2 Form File Upload into two entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I have a form in symfony which I send to the server with ajax/xhr2. It includes a textfield and possible files (none or multiple allowed). Therefore I created an entity named "post" which holds the submitted text, the user who did it and the date/time. Plus it is associated with a OneToMany relationship to an entity named "upload".

```
class Post{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Upload", mappedBy="post")
 */
private $uploads;
```

This entity holds all the relevant data on the uploaded file(s).

```
class Upload
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
 */
private $name;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $path;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $size;
```

In the Upload entity I also placed the upload methods as explained on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Now when I persist my post, the post class tries to upload the file instead of leaving it form the upload class. Thus I get an error that no method setUploads exists in the post class. When I add it, I get the error that the method received an instance of UploadedFile instead of Upload.

Does anyone have good advice how I could upload files the way I modeled the classes or how to create a better model?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fully explanation on how to upload files to Symfony2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step/17955934#17955934). As you guessed right, you need to add the method `setUploads()` to your `Post` entity. The uploaded file will be linked to the `Upload` entity not the `Post` itself.