# upload files in a mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload files and photos in my mobile app, but I cannot find how to do it.

I am using jQuery mobile library, but it doesn't seem to have any feature for doing that. I am also using Symfony2.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: are you using phonegap with JQM?

Comment: No, I am not using phonegap

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step

Comment: I know how to do it in Symfony. However, I need to do it in my mobile app. Selecting several photos at a time.