# Uploading file with Symfony2 - compare file name with uploaded files

Tags: php, symfony

I implement this functionality using this[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step) instruction but I don't know how to compare generated file name with uploaded files.

**Edit**:

I generate new file name using this code:

```
/**
 * Called before saving the entity
 * 
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{   
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us something. Surely, you have tried something so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the PHP function [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to compare filenames.