# Symfony2 Multiple File upload step by step

Tags: symfony, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I am learning symfony2, I've been looking everywhere for a good step by step example on how to make a multiple file upload and I couldn't find it.

I have already checked the online documentation on [file uploads](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)
but I could not figure out how to make it possible for multiple file uploads.
I thought a full step by step example on how to upload multiple files at once without using another bundle could be useful (something like [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step) would me realy appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PunkAveFileUploaderBundle](https://github.com/punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle) to upload multiple files at a time in symfony2 using [BlueImp jQuery file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/). Hope it will help you.