# Upload File dont persist

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine

I am new to the Symfony2 and I'm trying to upload a file using the Symfony2 cookbook documentation.
My problem is , my entity with the file is not persisting consequently my file is not uploaded

Here is my file entity

```
<?php


namespace JuridicoBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="JURIDICO_ANEXOS_TESTE")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JuridicoBundle\Repository\AnexoRepository")
 */
class Anexo {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Liminar" ,inversedBy="anexos", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="LIMINAR", referencedColumnName="cdliminar")
     **/
    private $liminar;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLiminar()
    {
        return $this->liminar;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $liminar
     */
    public function setLiminar($liminar)
    {
        $this->liminar = $liminar;
    }

    public $file;

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    private $temp;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
            $this->name = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        if ($file) {

            @unlink($file);
        }
    }


}
```

And my class with oneToMany relationship

```
<?php

namespace JuridicoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Liminar
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="juridico_liminar")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JuridicoBundle\Repository\LiminarRepository")
 */
class Liminar
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="cdliminar", type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cdprocesso", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $cdprocesso;

    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     * @ORM\Column(name="dtrecebimento", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dataRecebimento;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cdcliente", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $codigoCliente;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="nocliente", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nomeCliente;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cdcliente2", type="string" , length=20)
     */
    private $codigoCliente2;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="nocliente2", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nomeCliente2;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MotivoAcao", inversedBy="liminar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CDMOTIVO_ACAO", referencedColumnName="CDMOTIVO_ACAO")
     **/
    private $codigoMotivoAcao;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="motivo_obs", type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $motivoObservacao;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="multa", type="float")
     */
    private $multa;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cumprimento", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $cumprimento;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="valor", type="float")
     */
    private $valor;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="sem_valor", type="string" , length=100)
     */
    private $semValor;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="hospital", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $hospital;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="medico_solicitante", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $medicoSolicitante;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="cooperado", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $cooperado;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UnimedOrigem", inversedBy="liminar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UNIMED_ORIGEM", referencedColumnName="CDPRESTADOR")
     **/
    private $unimedOrigem;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="contrato", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $contrato;

    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     * @ORM\Column(name="dtcadastro", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dataCadastro;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcadastro", type="integer", length=6)
     */

    private $codigoCadastro;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Anexo", mappedBy="liminar", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $anexos;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->anexos = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAnexos()
    {
        $anexos = $this->anexos;
        foreach($anexos as $anexo) {
            $anexo->setLiminar($this);
        }
        return $this->anexos;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $anexo
     */
    public function setAnexos($anexos)
    {
        foreach($anexos as $anexo) {
            $anexo->setLiminar($this);
        }
        $this->anexos = $anexos;
    }

    public function addAnexo($anexo)
    {
        $anexo->setLiminar($this);
        $this->anexos[] = $anexo;
    }

    public function removeAnexo($anexo)
    {
        $this->anexos->removeElement($anexo);
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */

    public function getCodigoCadastro()
    {
        return $this->codigoCadastro;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoCadastro
     */
    public function setCodigoCadastro($codigoCadastro)
    {
        $this->codigoCadastro = $codigoCadastro;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Datetime
     */
    public function getDataCadastro()
    {
        return $this->dataCadastro;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Datetime $dataCadastro
     */
    public function setDataCadastro($dataCadastro)
    {
        $this->dataCadastro = $dataCadastro;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContrato()
    {
        return $this->contrato;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $contrato
     */
    public function setContrato($contrato)
    {
        $this->contrato = $contrato;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUnimedOrigem()
    {
        return $this->unimedOrigem;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $unimedOrigem
     */
    public function setUnimedOrigem($unimedOrigem)
    {
        $this->unimedOrigem = $unimedOrigem;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCooperado()
    {
        return $this->cooperado;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cooperado
     */
    public function setCooperado($cooperado)
    {
        $this->cooperado = $cooperado;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMedicoSolicitante()
    {
        return $this->medicoSolicitante;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $medicoSolicitante
     */
    public function setMedicoSolicitante($medicoSolicitante)
    {
        $this->medicoSolicitante = $medicoSolicitante;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHospital()
    {
        return $this->hospital;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $hospital
     */
    public function setHospital($hospital)
    {
        $this->hospital = $hospital;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSemValor()
    {
        return $this->semValor;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $semValor
     */
    public function setSemValor($semValor)
    {
        $this->semValor = $semValor;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getValor()
    {
        return $this->valor;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $valor
     */
    public function setValor($valor)
    {
        $this->valor = $valor;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCumprimento()
    {
        return $this->cumprimento;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cumprimento
     */
    public function setCumprimento($cumprimento)
    {
        $this->cumprimento = $cumprimento;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMulta()
    {
        return $this->multa;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $multa
     */
    public function setMulta($multa)
    {
        $this->multa = $multa;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMotivoObservacao()
    {
        return $this->motivoObservacao;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $motivoObservacao
     */
    public function setMotivoObservacao($motivoObservacao)
    {
        $this->motivoObservacao = $motivoObservacao;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigoMotivoAcao()
    {
        return $this->codigoMotivoAcao;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoMotivoAcao
     */
    public function setCodigoMotivoAcao($codigoMotivoAcao)
    {
        $this->codigoMotivoAcao = $codigoMotivoAcao;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNomeCliente2()
    {
        return $this->nomeCliente2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nomeCliente2
     */
    public function setNomeCliente2($nomeCliente2)
    {
        $this->nomeCliente2 = $nomeCliente2;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigoCliente2()
    {
        return $this->codigoCliente2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoCliente2
     */
    public function setCodigoCliente2($codigoCliente2)
    {
        $this->codigoCliente2 = $codigoCliente2;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNomeCliente()
    {
        return $this->nomeCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nomeCliente
     */
    public function setNomeCliente($nomeCliente)
    {
        $this->nomeCliente = $nomeCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigoCliente()
    {
        return $this->codigoCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoCliente
     */
    public function setCodigoCliente($codigoCliente)
    {
        $this->codigoCliente = $codigoCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Datetime
     */
    public function getDataRecebimento()
    {
        return $this->dataRecebimento;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Datetime $dataRecebimento
     */
    public function setDataRecebimento($dataRecebimento)
    {
        $this->dataRecebimento = $dataRecebimento;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCdprocesso()
    {
        return $this->cdprocesso;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cdprocesso
     */
    public function setCdprocesso($cdprocesso)
    {
        $this->cdprocesso = $cdprocesso;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}
```

Anyone can help?

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace JuridicoBundle\Controller;

use JuridicoBundle\Entity\Liminar;
use JuridicoBundle\Form\LiminarDetalheType;
use JuridicoBundle\Form\LiminarType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;



class LiminarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Realiza busca de autor do sistema através do nome
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     *
     * @Route("/busca-nome-liminar", name="busca-nome-liminar")
     *
     */
    public function consultaNomeAutor(Request $request){

        $response = new JsonResponse();

        $nome = $request->query->get("term");

        $processos = array();

        $resultado = array();

        $processos = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("JuridicoBundle:Liminar")
            ->consultaNome($nome);


        foreach ($processos as $processo) {
            $resultado[] = array(
                'label' => $processo["nomeCliente"],
                'value' => $processo["nomeCliente"],
                'id'    => $processo["id"]
            );
        }

        $response->setData($resultado);

        return $response;

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/salvar", name="salvar")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function salvarAction(Request $request) {
        $liminar = new Liminar();
        $form = $this->createForm(new LiminarDetalheType(),$liminar);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
                $liminar = $form->getData();

                $liminarRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('JuridicoBundle:Liminar');
                $liminarRepository->salvar($liminar);

                $this->addFlash('success', 'Liminar salva com sucesso');

        }
        return $this->render("JuridicoBundle:Liminar:nova.html.twig",
            array('formLiminar' => $form->createView()));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/editar-liminar/", name="editar-liminar")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function alterarAction(Request $request) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $liminarRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('JuridicoBundle:Liminar');
        $liminar = $liminarRepository->find($id);


        if(!$liminar){
            $this->createNotFoundException("Nenhuma Liminar disponível para edição.");
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new LiminarDetalheType(),$liminar);

        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if($form->isValid()){


            $liminar = $form->getData();

            try{
                $liminarRepository->alterar($liminar);

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
                    ->add('success', 'Atualizado com sucesso!');

            }catch (\Exception $e){

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'danger', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $this->render("JuridicoBundle:Liminar:liminar.html.twig",
                array('formLiminar' =>
                    $form->createView()));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/excluir", name="excluir")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function excluirAction(Request $request, Liminar $liminar) {

        $liminarRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("JuridicoBundle:Liminar");

        $liminar = $liminarRepository->find($liminar);

        if (!$liminar) {
            $this->createNotFoundException("Não existe essa Liminar");
        }
        try {
            $liminarRepository->excluir($liminar);

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
                ->add('success', 'Removido com sucesso!');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(''));

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->get('session')
                ->getFlashBag()
                ->add('danger', $e->getMessage());
        }

    }


}
```

My type form

```
<?php

namespace JuridicoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AnexoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'JuridicoBundle\Entity\Anexo',
            'csrf_protection' =>  false,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_csrf_token',
            // a unique key to help generate the secret token
            'intention'       => 'anexo',
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file','file',array(
                'label' => false));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'anexo';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code of controller?

Comment: Ok, now you can see my controller

Comment: Are you saw this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the example Symfony2 cookbook, the only difference is that I'm using a formType to build my form, not a controller. Is not the first time that i create a upload file class. But i don't know why my uploadfile class isn't persist, consequently my file isnt upload.

Comment: Are you use name "file" for input?

Comment: yes i edit my post, now you can see my anexoType