# How to using mp3 (audio) form field in joomla 2.5

Tags: components, joomla2.5

In my database, i have a field to save url of mp3 file! I'm trying using media type of form field but it only support for images!
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving a URL, then there is no need to use a media type, you only need a simple text box. If you want the form to allow a user to actually upload an MP3 then you can use a file type input box.

Comment: Yes, i want uload MP3, but i want filter only mp3 display when i select file?

Comment: No problem. Just add the ACCEPT attribute to the file input box and the user will only see the file type you specify. More here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: I'm trying using file type input box, but it only allow select file from computer, i want select file and upload to host of site?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Where else would a user upload a file from other than their computer? If you want them to enter the URL of an MP3 on the internet then your site copies the file to your server that is something completely different and you would not be able to guarantee that your site would be able to get the file.