# Opencart - Upload Specific File Type

Tags: file-upload, opencart, file-type

I am using OpenCart 1.5.6 and have two options for the customer to upload files to a product (image and video). When the users clicks upload I would like them to only be able to select specific file types from their computer while they browse for the files. So instead of "All Files" in the browser window, I want it to only allow .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .pdf, etc. for the image upload and for the video file I just want it to look for .mp4, .mov, .flv.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCdvA/

I have tried to use the accept attribute [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code for the product.tpl:

```
  <input type="button" accept="video/*,image/*" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button" >
  <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
```

I think that the problem is that it is type="button" and not type="file". Is there another way to limit the upload file type within the OpenCart product page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the jQuery plugin used. It is *AjaxUpload* which seems to be taken over by different developer (completely) and reworked (completely) and the links to the original (old) documentation are dead (completely).

Well, after exploring that jQuery plugin I have found out that it works this way: in the `ptoduct.tpl` You can see:

```html
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
new AjaxUpload('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>', {
    //...
});
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This means that for each option of type file this *AjaxUpload* is instanciated. Basically it only creates a DIV containing INPUT of type FILE with 0 opacity that is rendered above the *Upload File* button. This means that when user clicks on *Upload File* he clicks on the INPUT of type FILE instead (without knowing this). Now, looking at the code I can see that there is no possibility to set this `accept="image/*"` attribute because there is no support for this (original code):

```js
    _createInput: function(){ 
        var self = this;

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('name', this._settings.name);

        addStyles(input, {
            // ...
        });

        // ...
    },
```

So now if You'd like to add support for this, You'd need to change this code to this (file: `catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ajaxupload.js`, around line 350):

```js
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('name', this._settings.name);
        if (this._settings.accept) {
            input.setAttribute('accept', this._settings.accept);
        }
```

And change the code for plugin initializiation in `product.tpl` to:

```html
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
new AjaxUpload('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>', {
    <?php if ($option['product_option_id'] == <IMAGE_FILE_OPTION_ID>) { ?>
    accept: 'image/*',
    <?php } else if ($option['product_option_id'] == <VIDEO_FILE_OPTION_ID>) { ?>
    accept: 'video/*',
    <?php } ?>
    //...
});
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This should be enough.

Comment: This sounds great and kinda works. First I had to add a } in from of else if to not get an unexpected else error. I am having another problems with the else if statement. Basically when I add it to the file and upload, it doesn't allow me to click on the button. Only the first one I enter works. If I remove the else if statement they both work (although it doesn't limit one of them because the code is not there). Is there a reason that tow commands wouldn't work with the ajax code?

Comment: <?php if ($option['product_option_id'] == 228) { ?>
  accept: 'video/*',
    <?php } elseif  ($option['product_option_id'] == 227) { ?>
  accept: 'image/*';
    <?php } ?>

Comment: Here's the URL: http://zing-cards.com/dev/storefront/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=50

Comment: The Upload AR Video option works but the standard Upload File one doesn't

Comment: Found the error - somehow You must have written `accept: 'image/*';` instead of `accept: 'image/*',` - mind the **semicolon** in first (Yours) case and **comma** that should be there - **only for image** option. Fix this and it should work. I corrected the missing `}` in my code...