# Remove 'All Files' option from HTML file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using `<input type="file">` to upload *audio* files.

To do that I am using `accept="audio/*"`.  Because of this, the browser's file-select dialog shows only audio files by default.  However, there is an option called "All Files" in that dialog box that I don't want.

(note - Any solution in Javascript , jQuery and AngularJs is also welcome)

[image]

How can I disable/remove the "All Files" option?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe that this is outside the scope of the browser, and is more up to the OS. However, despite whatever the case is, I don't think that this is something that you should mess with anyway.

`accept` doesn't have the best support (although might not be an issue), but as you can see here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#audio the sheer number of allowed types probably falls outside of the scope of your application anyway. The best thing you should do is perform server side validation, using `accept` purely as a client indicator.

Also, while it is an older answer, I think it is still relevant and valid: [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Comment: so bottom line is, I can't disable 'All Files' ?

Comment: Yep. But the more important answer is that you shouldn't.

Comment: Absolutley right: This is an usability enhancement not a validation and also not a security feature. So don't really see a problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

It possible now by using window.showOpenFilePicker present in File System Access API. Only issue is its only available in Chrome since October 2020.

```
  const files = await window.showOpenFilePicker({     
    
    types: [
          {
            description: 'Audio Files',
            accept: {
              'audio/*': ['.mp3','.wav'],//Extensions you want to allow
            },
          },
        ],
        excludeAcceptAllOption: true, // this hides all files option
        multiple: false,
});
```

API Specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Note: This is not on a standards track.