# Remove "All Files" option from uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using

```
< input type="file" >
```

to upload files.

To upload only selective files i am using "accept". So dialog box contains my selected types of files extension. But there is an option of "All Files" which i do not want there.

How can I remove this option?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this can be done.  Certainly, not reliably, since it would depend on how the browser has chosen to implement this particular functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do (natively)  is  to check which file was selected  :

```
<input   id="uploadFile" type="file"  onchange="FileSelected(this)"  />
```

Script :

```
function FileSelected(sender)
{
    if (check(sender.value)) //check is you function to check extension 
    {...}
    else
    {...}
}
```

**Sample code :** ( check only jpg)
http://jsbin.com/sibose/2/edit

## Edit

in chrome . ie10 you can do :

```
<!-- (IE 10+, Chrome) -->
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
```

With FF :

```
<!-- (IE 10+, Chrome, Firefox) -->
<input type="file"
 accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

**demo** : http://jsbin.com/jihoku/2/edit

Comment: i am handling the validation through javascript. but i want the all files option to be removed in the first place :(

Comment: there's still "All Files" option in dropdown.

Comment: Then download `uploadify plugin` and do it unnativly using flash

Comment: notice that if uploadify sees new browser - it will use what ive done here ^. you should modify it to use flash and not html5

Comment: its same with uploadify too :(

Comment: Not everything can be done. **but** if a user has selected a wrong file : you can **spot it immediately** . I dont see where is the problem

Comment: ok i'll tell this to my manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114493/remove-all-files-option-from-html-file-input