# File input in HTML accept .pdf formats

Tags: html, file, pdf, input, http-accept-language

I try to upload a file which accepts only pdf formats.

```
<input type="file" name="test" accept=".pdf">
```

Although it filters all the files with .pdf extension, it shows also shortcuts with **.url** extensions. How can i make these shortcuts invisible to the users?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 'All Files' option from HTML file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114493/remove-all-files-option-from-html-file-input)

Comment: @Justcode So the only solution is the server side validation?

Comment: yes, I think that is the way to go