# How do you filter a file input so that it only shows one type of file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vbscript

How do you filter a file input so that it only shows one type of file? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<input type="file" value="*.docx"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `accept` attribute that you can add to the `<input>` element to only allow browsing of certain file extensions:

```
<input type="file" value="*.docx" accept=".doc,.docx" />
```

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

> If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifiers:
>
> - A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (E.g.: ".jpg,.png,.doc")
> - ...

Keep in mind that it's quite easy to bypass this "limitation" and anyone with minimal HTML knowledge will be able to browse and select "non-supported" file types by modifying the actual HMTL element on the page before clicking the browse button.

Comment: I'm programming an HTA and HTA doesn't support the accept attribute (it acts like IE7)

Comment: @DonaldDuck - that sounds like quite an important piece of information. Perhaps you should add all of your restrictions and environmental considerations in the body of your post.

Comment: I created a new question for an equivalent of `accept` in HTA. Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704801/equivalent-to-accept-attribute-in-hta) to see it.

Answer (score 0):

As Lix said it already, you can use accept attribute, you can use it as said in this page:

[HTML  accept Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)

but to be specific ".docx" extension has some problems with accept attribute in some browsers. I recommend you to use a java script check on from submit.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in VBScript that works:

```
<object id="Dlg" classid="CLSID:3050F4E1-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B" width="0" height="0"></object>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub OpenFile
     s = Dlg.openfiledlg(, , CStr("Word-documents (*.doc;*.docx;*.docm)|*.doc;*.docx;*.docm|"), CStr("Choose File"))
     If (Len(s) = 0) Then
          MsgBox "No file was selected."
     Else
          i2 = InStr(s, Chr(0))
          If i2 > 1 Then  s = Left(s, (i2 - 1))
          MsgBox "The selected file is " & s
     End If
End Sub
</script>
<button onclick="OpenFile">Open file</button>
```

Comment: Hmm - since you didn't specify `vbscript` as a tag on your question, this answer doesn't really fit the post. I've gone ahead and added that tag so that people might be able to find this content with greater ease in the future.