# Validate file field html tag file name, If it contain special character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I need to validate for file field, if it contains special character whichever is not correct for file field.

I am uploading my file and after it gets uploaded I am not able to open it if it has special charterer.

I need to validate :

1) file name - no special character

2) file size - limit the size

3) file format - video and only .mp4

> Note : Thanks for `istos` comment I am using [accept attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503561/1877909) but
>   it would not validate, I have to do validation in either JS or PHP.

I am using ajax call for my form instead of using `html form`.
I am not sure if I need to do this in client side (jQuery, JS) or server side (PHP) or both site.
Please help, Thanks

```js
$('body').on('change', '#gl_video_file', function(e) {
                var glVideoFiles = event.target.files;
                glVideoFileSplit = glVideoFiles[0].name.split(".");
                glVideoFileFormat = glVideoFileSplit[1];
                glVideoFileName = glVideoFileSplit[0].split(' ').join('_')
                alert ("File name : "+glVideoFileName)
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" placeholder="Video file" class="dupFile" id="gl_video_file">
```

Comment: Start with this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful then build from there.

Comment: Thanks @istos,it was very useful. I have added it But it will not validate the field. I can still upload image in video file tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to check your file name. On server side:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-]+(\.mp4)$/i', $filename)) {
    die ('Bad file name format.');
}
```

For the size, you can check:

```
if ($_FILES["fileinputname"]['size'] > $maxFileSize) {
    die('File size is too big.');
}
```

With jQuery to check the name:

```
if (!$('#filenameinputid').val().match(/^[a-z0-9_-]+(\.mp4)$/i)) {
    alert('Bad file name format.');
}
```

and  the size:

```
$('#filenameinputid').bind('change', function() {
    if (this.files[0].size > maxFileSize) {
        alert("File size is too big.");
    }
});
```

Comment: which would be preferable server side or client side ?

Comment: Both could be good. Todays, is a trend to not send and refresh the page, just do it on client side. BUT! **Always do a check on server side.** Client script could be manipulated.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering , Let me check it :)

Comment: You've used `e` in your function parameter later you tried get the `event`. Use the console to check errors: http://jsfiddle.net/0o8p9w85/4/

Comment: when I selected mp4 file with name "test343.mp4", it throws error ...sorry for bothering you again and again

Comment: Because the first check. What is that?

Comment: Even if I comment first check I get error in `second check : ` .... http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/0o8p9w85/5/