# C# - Upload File to Website

Tags: c#, html

There's an input tag on a website that I want to programmatically upload an image file to. The tag looks like this:

```
<input type="file" label="upload" ..>
```

I don't know how to interact with something like this. How would I input a specified image file to that tag?

I have this much:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Choose Images";
        ofd.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection elc = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            Image i = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
            foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
            {
                //Upload file here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">` to filter image files only. For more details you can see: [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

The browser won't let you upload a file programatically - that would be a major security issue - you would be able to copy any file from your visitors computer.

The user has to trigger the upload himself- manually.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful.

[WebClient.UploadFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.80).aspx)

Or maybe this:

[Multipart HTTP FILE POST](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268661-how-upload-file-via-c-code)