# Form file accept type in ReactJS

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have a simple form:

```
<form className="form-horizontal form-border" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div className="form-group">
         <label className="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
         <div className="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="patch_name" required="" placeholder="Patch name" />
         </div>
     </div>

     <div className="form-group">
         <label className="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
         <div className="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="patch_description" required="" placeholder="Patch description" />
         </div>
     </div>

     <div className="form-group">
         <label className="col-sm-3 control-label">Patch File</label>
         <div className="col-sm-4">
             <input type="file" accept="compress/*" name="patch_file" />
         </div>
     </div>

     <div className="form-group">
         <div className="col-sm-3" />
         <div className="col-sm-1">
             <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Create Patch" />
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

I want to be able to only accept `tar.gz` file uploads. The only "type" I've been able to get was `image/*`.

Where can I get a list of types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with React. Take a look at this answer, which describes how to use the HTML `accept` attribute: [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful/10503561#10503561)

The correct MIME type for `.gz` files is [`application/gzip`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6713). There is no official MIME type for `.tar.gz` (since `.tar.gz` isn't actually a file format, but rather a naming convention for a TAR file inside a `gzip` file). Sometimes `application/x-gtar` is used, but it's nonstandard (hence the `x-`) and YMMV. You can also use file extensions in `accept`, but support is spotty and none of the browsers I tested in handled the two dots in `.tar.gz` as we might expect.

The [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-accept) has the following note:

> Authors are encouraged to specify both any MIME types and any corresponding extensions when looking for data in a specific format.

With that in mind, your best bet is probably this:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/gzip, .gz" />
```

Comment: In my case for tar and tar.bz2 this was `'application/gzip, .tar, .tar.bz2'`