# Validate individual files in multiple file upload before uploading them to server

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, validation, file-upload

I have a form with 3 separate file input fields. I can't seem to find a way to individually validate their MIME types before uploading them to the server. (The first 2 are supposed to only allow MP3 files, while the last is only supposed to allow only JPEG files.)

How can I do this, or is it best to check the MIME type after the file is uploaded, then either keep it, or delete it and return an error message?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Full MP3 file
      <input type="file" name="file_array[]" id="file_array[]" tabindex="1" required>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Sample MP3 file (30-45 seconds)
      <input type="file" name="file_array[]" id="file_array[]" tabindex="2" required>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      JPEG Cover Art ( Recommended 400 x 400 px)
      <input type="file" name="file_array[]" id="file_array[]" tabindex="3" required>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:100%;">    </progress>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submitbtn" onclick="uploadFile()">
  </div>

</form>
```

and this is upload.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "../artists/$id/temp/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript validation is also advisory at best. You're better of with an [`<input type=file accept="image/*">`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) filter. You *still have to* assert in PHP if the file contents are what the browser claimed/guessed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use validation at the client side to make the experience more smooth. as Mario pointed, you can use something like this to accept only mp3 files:

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp3" name="file_array[]" id="file_array[]" tabindex="1" required>
```

But since you can't trust user data, you must also add server side validation. For example:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){

    if ($i == 2){
        if($type_array[2] != 'image/jpeg'){
            echo 'Invalid file type: ' . $type_array[2];
            break;
        } 
    }
    else {
        if($type_array[$i] != 'audio/mp3'){
            echo 'Invalid file type: ' . $type_array[$i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],"../artists/$id/temp/".$name_array[$i])){
        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
}
```

Tested the above code and it seems to be working for me.

Notes:

if you already know the number of uploaded files don't use `count` since it could cause a risk, and if you want the number of uploaded files at a time to be variable, then make sure the `count` result doesn't exceed the max value. also use `count` outside of the loop so its only calculated once.

there are other more strict ways to validate file types, but this what I got now.

hope this helps and give feedback if I wronged in any how.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the data is only available **after** upload. You may try to tell the browser (if capable) to send only specific mime-types using this:

```
<input type="file1" name="image" accept="image/*">
<input type="file2" name="pdf" accept="application/pdf">
```