# html5 pattern validation for file not working

Tags: html, file, validation

I searched in Google there has no option for validate file by using URL pattern.

I also have tried in my site. But pattern for `file` not working. Check my code -

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="mp3file_name" name="mp3file_name"  pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(mp3))$)" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/mp3" required="required" />
```

Attribute `accept` working fine but I need to validate If I will  uploading other files except `mp3`

Comment: you can use javascript function along with button to validate..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the pattern and just use:

```html
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="mp3file_name" name="mp3file_name" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/mp3" required="required" />
```

Also as said by [Mave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255033/mave):

> The accept attribute is incredibly useful. It is a hint to browsers to only show files that are allowed for the current input. While it can typically be overridden by users, it helps narrow down the results for users by default, so they can get exactly what they're looking for without having to sift through a hundred different file types.

Comment: Your code accepted all files like `.doc`, `.zip` etc.

Comment: @Chinu What browser are you using? It doesn't allow me to add anything other than `.mpg` and `.mp3`!

Comment: Click on browse bottom and select `All Files ('*')` then choose any other file

Comment: I am using `mozilla firefox version - 39.0.3`

Comment: ^ That I don't think you can stop. It is a feature of all platforms.

Comment: I am using Chrome. And what you say is normal expected behaviour that you need to handle in server side by reading the MIME type.

Comment: I know i can validate in server side. But Just want to know is there any option for validate file extension in url pattern? I am using popup. once page refresh then popup will disappear

Comment: Nopes. You can't do that buddy! `:(`

Answer (score 0):

Please see [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful):

> The accept attribute is incredibly useful. It is a hint to browsers to only show files that are allowed for the current input. While it can typically be overridden by users, it helps narrow down the results for users by default, so they can get exactly what they're looking for without having to sift through a hundred different file types.

You can make it easier for users to browse through their files, but ultimately you have no control over it, as it is user input. Make sure you check the file in whatever language you receive the form in.