# IE11 input type="file" accept=".xls" additional categories appear

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, input-type-file

In IE11 whenever i use accept attribute in my input, besides the usual "All files" and "Custom files(.xls) there's two additional categories appear: "Images" and "HTML". Is there a way to remove the unwanted categories?

The problem can be reproduced for me at any input with accept attribute, like in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinjoseph/BkcKQ/

```
IE 10+, Edge, Chrome:<br />
<label>.xls,.xlsx files</label>
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
<br />
<br />
IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, Firefox:<br />
<label>.xls,.xlsx files (using MIME-types)</label>
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" />
<br />
<br />
<h3>
Recommended way of achieving file type filter:
</h3>
IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, Firefox:<br />
<label>.xls,.xlsx files (using both extensions and MIME-types)</label>
<input type="file"
     accept=".xls,.xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel" />
<br />
<br /> <br />
<br />
    <b>Note:</b><p>Edge allows to choose files of any type by default, even if accept attribute is set, although it adds a custom filter list to the file-select dialog box. The user must manually apply the filter from the file-select dialog box.</p>
```

Comment: The `accept` attribute is not for file extensions. See the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533060(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE, as it often is, is not standards compliant. The HTML standard allows for mime types as well as file extensions preceded by a full stop. By comparison, IE's spec for the accept attribute only mentions mime types. Here's what the official spec says:

> The accept attribute may be specified to provide user agents with a hint of what file types will be accepted.
>
> If specified, the attribute must consist of a set of comma-separated tokens, each of which must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the following:
>
> - **The string** "audio/*"
>     Indicates that sound files are accepted.
> - **The string** "video/*"
>     Indicates that video files are accepted.
> - **The string** "image/*"
>     Indicates that image files are accepted.
> - **A valid MIME type with no parameters**
>     Indicates that files of the specified type are accepted.
> - **A string whose first character is a U+002E FULL STOP character (.)**
>     Indicates that files with the specified file extension are accepted.

Sources:
 - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-accept
 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
 - [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)