# input file accept params seems not working at all

Tags: html, forms

I want to filter files user can select into `<input type='file'>`

So I wrote :
`<input class="form-control" accept="video/*" name="my_video" id="my_video" type="file">` for video

and `<input class="form-control" accept="image/*" name="my_picture" id="my_picture" type="file">` for an image

I do tests with Linux browsers :

- Firefox 53.0 (64 bits)
- Chromium 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)

both do not filter file types.

I looked around on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful). Syntax seems good. But even examples from that discussion does not work for me.

I checked on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs) as well. Nothing to help me.

I also tried to put directly file extension like `accept="png"` `accept=".png"`, `accept="*.png"`. With same result.

Does someone have a clue to make `accept` parameter work?

Answer (score 0):

Code is too simple and it shows no error on Chrome.
But for cross-browser functionality you can use jquery code or [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo)

Comment: What do you mean by "too simple" ? The code works as file input field. Only the filter part does not.

Comment: Thanks for bootstrap link, that mainly helps to make pretty input fields. Anyway [the code behind](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-image-dimensions-demo) looks very similar as mine.