# HTML file input — "accept" attribute not working

Tags: html, cross-browser, mime-types

After reading through the [comments on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful), I came up with the following syntax for the accept attribute:

**Images**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, .jpeg, .png, .gif">
```

**Audio**

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/x-wav, .mp3, .wav">
```

This works perfectly on desktop browsers, but does not appear to filter files at all on iOS or Android.

Are there any cross-browser solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get the `accept` attribute to work for mobile. Ultimately I had to add an [onchange handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) to the input (general idea shown below).

Keep in mind, you'll still want to use the `accept` attribute as shown in my question, because it will work on desktop.

```
const supportedExtensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'];

const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
  const path = target.value.split('.');
  const extension = `${path[path.length - 1]}`;

  if (supportedExtensions.includes(extension)) {
    // TODO: upload
  } else {
      // TODO: show "invalid file type" message to user

      // reset value
      target.value = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The detail listing of browser support for "accept" attribute is listed in [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp). Have a look. It may help you.

Comment: I tried just now on Android. The behavior is not exactly same but filter is working on Android for me. e.g. when I provided option `.doc` then only option to select `document` appeared. When I had only `image/*` then camera, drive etc. where provided but `document` option was not.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, found this page, here is my workaround using `onChange` event.

I know this isn't true filtering and this is pretty ugly (I don't it), but it works indeed. I tested on my iOS and Android devices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 let file;
 function checkFile() {
  file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  if (file.type != "image/png") {
   file = null;
   document.getElementById('image').remove();
   let div = document.getElementById('div');
   let image = document.createElement('input');
   image.setAttribute('type', 'file');
   image.setAttribute('id', 'image');
   image.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png');
   image.setAttribute('onchange', 'checkFile()');
   div.appendChild(image);
   window.alert('unsupported file type');
  }
 }
</script>
<div id="div">
 <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/png" onchange="checkFile()">
</div>
```