# How to make HTML file input select only document formats on Mobile devices?

Tags: android, html, ios, file

If i put `accept="image/*"` it opens gallery with camera button. If i put `accept="video/*"` it opens files with other files grayed(disabled) and suggest camera app.

I tryed some variants, but no success for documents on Android. Want `accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.ods,.odt,.pdf"` but file input accepts video,audio,images etc too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML file input — "accept" attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495047/html-file-input-accept-attribute-not-working)

Comment: It appears that mobile browsers do not fully support the `accept` attribute