# select a file without specifying the extension in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder with thumbnails. These can be .jpg or .gif or .png etc. 
How can I select a file with only the name using javascript?

For example if there is a file called **tree.jpg** I want to find it with only using **tree**. The folder in which these thumbnails are located is always the same. Below is the code snippet I'm using. My question is about the line with *var src*. In that line I want to find the file in the folder *thumbnails* with only using the name.

```
(projects is a json file)
function buildWork(projects) {
 var container = document.getElementById('projects');
 var row = document.createElement('div');
 row.className = 'row no-gutters';
 container.appendChild(row);

for(var i in projects) {
  col = document.createElement('div');
  col.className = 'col-6 col-md-4 item thumbnail';

  var src = "thumbnails/" + project.name;

  col.innerHTML = '<img src='+ src +'></img>';
  row.appendChild(col);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean without out the extension? What is the input supposed to do? You can not really do much with the input because of security restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by select? If you are talking about having a list of filenames and only picking the file extensions you listed, you can do `string.match(\.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.png\);` which means anything.gif or anything.jpg or anything.png

Comment: Do you mean like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503561/863110) answer?

Comment: I think he wants to select a file with filename without file extension, like "image" instead of "image.img"

Comment: I updated the question with your feedback. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-browser JavaScript isn't permitted to list files on your harddrive. If you want to try several known file extensions against a *server*'s filesystem, you can use this:

```
const fname = "tree";
const exts = ['.png', '.jpg', ... ];

let queries = exts.map(ext => fetch(`${fname}${ext}`).then(response));

Promise.all(queries).then(responses => {
    // Only one response will return "ok":
    // It will be at the same index as the correct extension
    // in the `exts` array.

    // This will hold the extension of the FIRST extension that returns
    // from the server successfully:
    let correctExtension = exts[responses.map(r => r.ok).indexOf(true)];

    let trueFileName = fname + correctExtension;
});
```

**[EDIT]** This method should still work for your updated question; however, you're still requesting *every* file from the server and hoping one of them exists. (The `trueFileName` var will hold `tree.jpg` at the end, provided that this file exists on the server.)

Your other option is to use API-style redirects on your HTTP server; but that's a *whole different story* and has no effect on your JavaScript.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not a huge change, but hopefully more explicit.